# java.sql.SQLException: Smart-large-object error informix

Tags: java, jdbc, insert, informix

I am trying to insert blob into table in informix database using JDBC query. However am getting this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Smart-large-object error.
at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:413)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.a(IfxSqli.java:3494)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.E(IfxSqli.java:3807)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.dispatchMsg(IfxSqli.java:2610)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveMessage(IfxSqli.java:2526)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executeCommand(IfxSqli.java:940)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxResultSet.b(IfxResultSet.java:303)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxStatement.c(IfxStatement.java:1273)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(IfxPreparedStatement.java:421)
at etaxarchive.FillDataManager.insertIntoTable(FillDataManager.java:196)
at etaxarchive.FillDataManager.fillTableData(FillDataManager.java:112)
at etaxarchive.ETaxArchiveManager.archiveData(ETaxArchiveManager.java:89)
at etaxarchive.ETaxArchive.main(ETaxArchive.java:33)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ISAM error: Lock Timeout Expired
at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:413)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.E(IfxSqli.java:3812)
... 10 more
```

Does anybody knows how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting a BLOB which using this line of code:

```
InputStream binaryStream = rs.getBlob(i).getBinaryStream();
```

I change it to this line of code:

```
InputStream test = rs.getBinaryStream(i);
```

and I was not getting this exception again.

Maybe this was not the problem, but for me it works.